# Tensor Index Manipulation

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, index-notation, special-relativity

I am trying to study General Relativity and I thought about starting with some index gymnastics. I found a worksheet online and I am stuck with a simple problem.
I have to prove that $\partial_{\mu} g^{\nu\rho} = -g^{\nu\kappa}g^{\rho\lambda}\partial_{\mu}g_{\lambda\kappa}$

LHS seems to me like it should be zero, but other than that I have no clue.

available info is that all Greek letters are from 0 to 3.

Also, do you know any resources with solved problems like that I can work on?

Comment: Why do you think that the LHS should vanish?

Comment: I suppose that you think that LHS should vanish since in Special Relativity, a coordinate system can be chosen so that $g$ has constant components. But in General Relativity that is not the case. Also, neither LHS nor RHS is a tensor. Therefore, just because it might vanish in one coordinate system it doesn't have to vanish in another coordinate system.

Comment: Small direct hint: By definition of the inverse metric, $g^{\nu \sigma} g_{\sigma \lambda} = \delta^{\nu}_{\lambda}$. Differentiate both sides with respect to $\mu$.